# Google Colab local runtime connect button disabled

Tags: google-colaboratory

I want to connect Google Colab to a local runtime. I have done all the [instructions](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) and started my jupyter server.
However, when I pasted the URL to the text bar, the CONNECT button remained disabled. Does anyone know why?

[Screenshot of the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNlg8.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same problem!